# Find string in html page using mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am trying to find if a given string, lets say "Hello" exists in a given page. So far I have the following:

```
agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('http://www.google.de/')
```

and what should I do now? I have seen the search method, but it only accepts XPath/CSS expressions. I could try to use xpath to search, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply do for general text search:

```
page.body.include?('Hello')
```

However when searching a particular html node I recommend using css selectors like that:

```
page.parser.css('#my_container_element').text.include? 'Hello'
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the first method to do the simple search.

Comment: That doesn't work with non ASCII search.

page.body.encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
page.encoding
=> "UTF-8"